# how to encode password with java in the same way that FOSUserBundle do

Tags: java, fosuserbundle, encode, salt

My database contains a table User with salt and password columns.
FOSUserBundle use sha512

```
# app/config/security.yml
# ...

encoders:
    "FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface": sha512
```

But it is not all, there is others parameters like number of iteration, hashing algorithm,cost,key_lenght,encode as base64 etc, i taked an image for for those parameters.
[image: Parameters of SHA512 with FOSUser-symfony 3.3]

In my java application, i need to encode the input password in the same way that fosuser do...
I tried to use org.apache.commons.codec.digest.Crypt, i don't know how to fix the parameters like fosuser do

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat has a API level class `MessageDigestCredentialHandler` that does most of what you're describing.  If it's not exactly what you need, its source should give you enough of a pointer how to handle salts and iterations though.

First it can encode, or mutate, a password:

```
MessageDigestCredentialHandler credentialHandler = new MessageDigestCredentialHandler();
credentialHandler.setAlgorithm("SHA-512");
credentialHandler.setSaltLength(16);
credentialHandler.setIterations(5);
credentialHandler.mutate("password");
-> 5e0bdcf374c9c36b8930f23579ca0297$5$2c72f01ce132a1d070e67ad4730f3c26dba6d1dce7d32c6d8fe127afc952cd02308bdbdd45333e71f4dfed57bc5288ce501da30228907b9d49f5932896c025a2
```

Note how the resulting string has a salt then a `$` then the number of iterations, another `$` and the (hex) encoded password.

If it's hex encoding that's being used in your database, you're in a good place to match a password too:

```
MessageDigestCredentialHandler credentialHandler = new MessageDigestCredentialHandler();
credentialHandler.setAlgorithm("SHA-512");
String salt = "5e0bdcf374c9c36b8930f23579ca0297";
int iterations = 5;
String hexPassword = "2c72f01ce132a1d070e67ad4730f3c26dba6d1dce7d32c6d8fe127afc952cd02308bdbdd45333e71f4dfed57bc5288ce501da30228907b9d49f5932896c025a2";
credentialHandler.matches("password", salt + "$" + iterations + "$" + hexPassword);
-> true
```

If the salt and/or password are base 64 encoded, there's more to do, but take a look at the [source for MessageDigestCredentialHandler.matches(String, String)](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina/8.0.15/org/apache/catalina/realm/MessageDigestCredentialHandler.java#MessageDigestCredentialHandler.matches%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%29).  It does handle base64 encoding in there too, but from reading through it looks like there's no support for multiple iterations with that.  I'd suggest to look how it did the iterations for the hex encoded route.